# Cloud Foundry Buildpack environment access

Tags: cloud, buildpack, cloud-foundry, stackato

I am trying to customize a Cloud Foundry buildpack and wanted to know if (within the buildpack) is it possible to obtain the Org and Space the application is being  being pushed to?

Answer (score 1):

You can check this documentation here:
https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/environment-variable.html

Acessing the VCAP_APPLICATION env variable you can obtain the several useful attributes related to the application (e.g., space).